# Devices says IPhone but application can still be downloaded for ipad?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I recently pushed an application to appstore. Now i have no idea why, but it says that its compatible with ipad too. In Deployment info i picked IPhone only. How is this possible and how can i change this fast.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have chosen iPhone in Deployment info. The app will still get install in iPad. Here are list you can chose in deployment info.

**Universal** :- These apps are designed to work on both iPhone and iPad.
When running on an iPad, these apps confirms to the larger screen of iPad as well as screen of iPhone.

**iPhone apps** :- These are apps designed specifically for iPhone. These apps can still run on iPad. However they will run on iPhone compatibility mode. There are some apps that utilize unique features of the iPhone such as ability to place phone calls. These apps will be unavailable to iPad.

**iPad** :- Designed specifically for iPad. Cannot install on iPhone.